# How do I increment an integer by the user's input in C++ within a loop and keep it incremented when the loop starts over?

Tags: c++, loops, increment

This is part of the code for an aggregate taxi program for four taxi companies. I need to increment each taxi company when the user adds items to their cart and calculate the cost for the chosen company. Finally the program needs to return to the main menu. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    cout<<"Welcome to Lawrence Aggregation Service"<< endl;
    //main menu
    int menu_select;
    cout<< "Please select from the following options"<< endl
        << "Purchase mileage vouchers from:"<< endl
        << "1 - Checker Cab"<< endl
        << "2 - GTS Lawrence"<< endl
        << "3 - Jayhawk Taxi"<< endl
        << "4 - RedyCab"<< endl
        << "Or"<< endl
        << "5 - View Cart"<< endl
        << "6 - Exit" << endl;
    cin>> menu_select;

    while ((menu_select) >=1 && (menu_select) <= 6)
    {    
        //user's menu choice
        //cab companies for incrementing miles
        int checker_sum;
        int checker;
        int gts;
        int jhawk;
        int redyc;

        //taxi company selection
        if (menu_select >= 1 && menu_select <= 4)
        {
            int mileage;
            cout<< "How many miles would you like to purchase?"<< endl;
            cin>> mileage;

            //checker cab selection
            if (menu_select == 1)
            {
                int menu_opt;
                double price_flat;
                double price_miles;
                double mileage_cost;
                price_flat = 30.00;
                price_miles = 0.00;
                mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
                checker_sum = (checker + mileage);
                cout<< "That will be $" <<(mileage_cost)<<
                    " with Checker Cab. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;
                cout<<"You have " <<checker<< " miles with Checker cab."<< endl;    
            }

            //gts lawrence selection
            else if (menu_select == 2)
            {
                int menu_opt;
                double price_flat;
                double price_miles;
                double mileage_cost;
                price_flat = 5.00;
                price_miles = .20;
                mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
                cout<< "That will be $" << mileage_cost <<
                    " with GTS Lawrence. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;

            }
            else if (menu_select == 3)
            {
                int menu_opt;
                double price_flat;
                double price_miles;
                double mileage_cost;
                price_flat = 10.00;
                price_miles = .05;
                mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
                cout<< "That will be $" << mileage_cost <<
                    " with Jayhawk Taxi. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;

            }

            else if (menu_select == 4)
            {
                int menu_opt;
                double price_flat;
                double price_miles;
                double mileage_cost;
                price_flat = 0;
                price_miles = 1.10;
                mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
                cout<< "That will be $" << mileage_cost <<
                    " with RedyCab. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain where in your current code you "increment a taxi company"?

Comment: It may help to give an example flow of what you want to see.

Comment: You really should start with design, not with code. Where are your data structures?

Comment: If you want the value of a variable to persist between loop iterations, you need to declare it in an outer scope before the loop.

Comment: How do you propose to implement the `view_cart` function? Think about it. Then you will find the flaws in your program. I hope you are familiar with basic concepts of arrays and structures. You will have to store each order separately. Do consider using a `struct` for the orders. This struct will contain details particular to a mileage voucher order and also a count variable which will be increased as and when an order is placed for that particular mileage voucher.

Answer (score -1):

For starters you should declare:

```
int checker_sum;
    int checker;
    int gts;
    int jhawk;
    int redyc;
```

outside the while loop so that the variables aren't declared multiple times

As for the increment you were mentioning what you could do is create a variable:

```
int totalCost;
```

You will have to declare this variable somewhere in the main that is outside of any of the while loops. For instance:

```
int main()
{
     int totalCost = 0;
     cout<<"Welcome to Lawrence Aggregation Service"<< endl;
    //main menu
    int menu_select;
    cout<< "Please select from the following options"<< endl;
```

You will have to do this so that you can change the value of the total cost in any of the loops;

Once you have declared this what you could do is:

```
if (menu_select == 1)
        {
            int menu_opt;
            double price_flat;
            double price_miles;
            double mileage_cost;
            price_flat = 30.00;
            price_miles = 0.00;
            mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
            checker_sum = (checker + mileage);
            cout<< "That will be $" <<(mileage_cost)<<
                " with Checker Cab. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;
            cout<<"You have " <<checker<< " miles with Checker cab."<< endl;
            totalCost = totalCost + mileage_cost
            // you could also do totalCost += mileage_cost

        }
```

If you do this in every loop then (since you declared the variable outside all the loops) it will add all the payments that you make into that one variable. And then when the user wants to View their cart you could put:

```
else if(menu_select == 5)
{
      //whatever code you want
      cout << "Total: " << totalCost;
      //whatever code you want
}
```

What you want to do to loop back to the main menu is put the whole thing into a while loop:

```
#include<iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int totalCost = 0;
     cout<<"Welcome to Lawrence Aggregation Service"<< endl;
     //main menu
     int menu_select;
while(menu_select != 6)
{
cout<< "Please select from the following options"<< endl
    << "Purchase mileage vouchers from:"<< endl
    << "1 - Checker Cab"<< endl
    << "2 - GTS Lawrence"<< endl
    << "3 - Jayhawk Taxi"<< endl
    << "4 - RedyCab"<< endl
    << "Or"<< endl
    << "5 - View Cart"<< endl
    << "6 - Exit" << endl;
cin>> menu_select;
//user's menu choice
    //cab companies for incrementing miles
    int checker_sum;
    int checker;
    int gts;
    int jhawk;
    int redyc;
while ((menu_select) >=1 && (menu_select) <= 6)
{
    //taxi company selection
    if (menu_select >= 1 && menu_select <= 4)
    {
        int mileage;
        cout<< "How many miles would you like to purchase?"<< endl;
        cin>> mileage;

        //checker cab selection
        if (menu_select == 1)
        {
            int menu_opt;
            double price_flat;
            double price_miles;
            double mileage_cost;
            price_flat = 30.00;
            price_miles = 0.00;
            mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
            checker_sum = (checker + mileage);
            cout<< "That will be $" <<(mileage_cost)<<
                " with Checker Cab. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;
            cout<<"You have " <<checker<< " miles with Checker cab."         << endl;
            totalCost = totalCost + mileage_cost;
            // or totalCost += mileage_cost;

        }

        //gts lawrence selection
        else if (menu_select == 2)
        {
            int menu_opt;
            double price_flat;
            double price_miles;
            double mileage_cost;
            price_flat = 5.00;
            price_miles = .20;
            mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
            cout<< "That will be $" << mileage_cost <<
                " with GTS Lawrence. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;
           totalCost = totalCost + mileage_cost;
            // or totalCost += mileage_cost;

        }
        else if (menu_select == 3)
        {
            int menu_opt;
            double price_flat;
            double price_miles;
            double mileage_cost;
            price_flat = 10.00;
            price_miles = .05;
            mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
            cout<< "That will be $" << mileage_cost <<
                " with Jayhawk Taxi. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;
            totalCost = totalCost + mileage_cost;
            // or totalCost += mileage_cost;

        }

        else if (menu_select == 4)
        {
            int menu_opt;
            double price_flat;
            double price_miles;
            double mileage_cost;
            price_flat = 0;
            price_miles = 1.10;
            mileage_cost = mileage* price_miles + price_flat;
            cout<< "That will be $" << mileage_cost <<
                " with RedyCab. Thank you."<< endl<< endl;
            totalCost = totalCost + mileage_cost;
            // or totalCost += mileage_cost;
        }
        else if(menu_select == 5)
        {
            /whatever code you want
           cout << "Total: " << totalCost;
           //whatever code you want
        }
     }
}
}
return 0;
```

}

Notice how I moved the: `int menu_select` to above the while loop because if it was anywhere below the while loop, then the compiler will report an error since you are using `menu_select` before it is declared.

I hope this was helpful and have a great time coding :).